# Multiple Prometheus metrics in single query issue

Tags: prometheus, promql

I am trying to combine two Prometheus queries working separately in Grafana but I can't get it working when combined into single one.

First query:

```
sum by(container, namespace) (
 increase(
  kube_pod_container_status_restarts_total{namespace!~\"excluded-namespace.*\"}
 [10m])
)
```

It returns time series like this:

```
{container="alertmanager", namespace="mimir"}
```

Second query:

```
kube_pod_status_reason{reason=~"^(Evicted|Shutdown|NodeAffinity|NodeLost|UnexpectedAdmissionError)$"}`
```

It returns time series like this:

```
{__name__="kube_pod_status_reason", gitops_jenkins_x_io_pipeline="namespaces", helm_sh_chart="kube-state-metrics-4.30.0", instance="10.1.1.110:8080", job="kubernetes-service-endpoints", namespace="y", node="ip-x.eu-west-1.compute.internal", pod="x-y-78b5bd99d7-lbdvh", reason="Evicted", service="prometheus-kube-state-metrics", uid="x"}
```

My attempt to combine them:

```
sum by(container, namespace) (
 increase(
  kube_pod_container_status_restarts_total{namespace!~"excluded-namespace.*"}
  [10m]) 
 * on(pod, container, namespace) group_right() 
 kube_pod_status_reason{reason=~"^(Evicted|Shutdown|NodeAffinity|NodeLost|UnexpectedAdmissionError)$"}
)
```

Above just not returning anything.

If I get rid of `group_right()` then it returns error: `Found duplicate series for the match group` and throws a list pods evicted in one (the same) of the namespaces in the Grafana error window:

```
Failed to evaluate queries and expressions: failed to execute query A: execution: found duplicate series for the match group {namespace="bull-exporter", pod="x-bull-exporter-bull-exporter-78b5bd99d7-lbdvh"} on the right hand-side of the operation: [{__name__="kube_pod_status_reason", gitops_jenkins_x_io_pipeline="namespaces", helm_sh_chart="kube-state-metrics-4.30.0", instance="10.1.1.110:8080", job="kubernetes-service-endpoints", namespace="bull-exporter", node="ip-x.eu-west-1.compute.internal", pod="x-bull-exporter-bull-exporter-78b5bd99d7-lbdvh", reason="NodeAffinity", service="prometheus-kube-state-metrics", uid="x"}, {__name__="kube_pod_status_reason", gitops_jenkins_x_io_pipeline="namespaces", helm_sh_chart="kube-state-metrics-4.30.0", instance="10.1.1.110:8080", job="kubernetes-service-endpoints", namespace="bull-exporter", node="ip-x.eu-west-1.compute.internal", pod="x-bull-exporter-bull-exporter-78b5bd99d7-lbdvh", reason="Evicted", service="prometheus-kube-state-metrics", uid="x"}];many-to-many matching not allowed: matching labels must be unique on one side
```

If I remove `pod` or `container` from `on` clause then I am getting:

```
Failed to evaluate queries and expressions: failed to execute query A: execution: found duplicate series for the match group {namespace="kubecost", pod="cost-analyzer-7f8646cd85-72v78"} on the left hand-side of the operation: [{container="cost-model", gitops_jenkins_x_io_pipeline="namespaces", helm_sh_chart="kube-state-metrics-4.30.0", instance="10.1.1.110:8080", job="kubernetes-service-endpoints", namespace="kubecost", node="ip-x.eu-west-1.compute.internal", pod="cost-analyzer-7f8646cd85-72v78", service="prometheus-kube-state-metrics", uid="x"}, {container="cost-analyzer-frontend", gitops_jenkins_x_io_pipeline="namespaces", helm_sh_chart="kube-state-metrics-4.30.0", instance="10.1.1.110:8080", job="kubernetes-service-endpoints", namespace="kubecost", node="ip-x.eu-west-1.compute.internal", pod="cost-analyzer-7f8646cd85-72v78", service="prometheus-kube-state-metrics", uid="x"}];many-to-many matching not allowed: matching labels must be unique on one side
```

Comment: A couple more questions: by combining do you mean, just adding of labels form one to another? Are you sure that you wanted multiplication to be inside of `sum by` and not on the outside?

Comment: What I want is to get reason label as a addition to container and namespace labels to post it in Grafana alert.